# ULONGLONG value corrupted in WinPE

Tags: mfc, winpe

I have an MFC app running in WinPE (Windows Preinstallation Environment), and I'm trying to make a method call with a 64-bit value in a ULONGLONG as a parameter.  I've determined that the value is correct (ie. 0x1b432d6000) before the call, but is corrupt (ie. 0x432d60000000000a) inside the call.  The value is initially allocated on the stack immediately before the call, and I've tried passing it by value, reference, and pointer.

The call works correctly in the debugger on my development machine.

What could be causing this?

Comment: FWIW, there's no reason for you to make this a "community wiki" post - you're the one with the problem, it's a very specific problem, and so any likely edits will be from you as well. CW is generally used for more general-interest questions, FAQs, polls, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Check function signatures - sounds like you might be calling the function using an incorrect calling convention.